# Pyarrow: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I have a dataframe with following dtype:

```
[2020-02-06 19:15:06,579] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - 
campanha                      object
chave_sistema_origem           int64
valor_ajustado                object
```

The column `valor_ajustado` has some value that is throwing me an exception when I try to write a parquet file using `df.to_parquet(buffer, index=False)`

```
[2020-02-06 19:15:06,597] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - an integer is required (got type str)
...
  File "/Users/jackhammer/.virtualenvs/python373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py", line 540, in convert_column
    result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 207, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 78, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
```

I know that column `valor_ajustado` has values like:

> 0
>
> 123,48
>
> 1
>
> 493,987

Anyone knows why it's trying to manipulate integers instead of keep column as an object?

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the `valor_ajustado` column? Are they all of the same type?

Comment: You can use .astype('str') to explicitly use string as data type.

Comment: Comma can mean several things. In some countries digital point is actually comma. E.g. Eastern part of Europe, Germany, France, uses it that way. That seems to be the case here. In other countries comma is a helper to grasp the order of magnitude easier, separating the groups of thousands. 1,000,000 is one million. But here 123,48 indicates that this is the former case: hundred-twenty-three plus fractional part.
That's way pandas can't be sure how to comprehend the values, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

There is no data type in Apache Arrow to hold Python objects so a supported strong data type has to be inferred (this is also true of Parquet files). I would cleansing the `valor_adjustado` column to make sure all the values are numeric (there must be a string or some other bad value within).

Answer (score 3):

I found this error after a doing a `pandas.merge` that yielded a dataframe with mixed datatypes in several columns.

Fixed with an explicit type change (there is likely a more elegant way to do this)

```
for col in int_cols:
   df[col] = df[col].astype(int, copy=False)

# now succeeds
df.to_feather(fn)
```

Comment: I stumbled on this with a column of strings that I had [mistakenly] assumed were already datetime, format. Applying ".to_datetime()" solved the problem, but it took me a little while to debug because the pyarrow error message was not "Datetime required, got str".